# Will content approval workflow send email alert and show up in tasks?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, 2013, content, content-approval

If I used default content approval workflow for both Lists and Pages, will it send email alert to approver when a new item is posted?
Secondly will the pending tasks to approve items show up in task list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will. When a task is assigned to a user, that user will get an email with the details.